# Get status of building and deployment on AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-amplify

I am building telegram bridge to get status of building and deployment of my web-app which is running on AWS amplify.
Already succeed to make telegram bot and connect topic, but still not sure how to catch event of success or fails of amplify building and deployment.

If someone knows approach, I will be appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @JamesLiu! Were you able to find any good approach? I'm looking for the solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was to create event inside the `amplify.yaml` Amplify Buildspec file. on every steps eg. backend : phases , frontend: phases and test phases.

eg.

```yaml
frontend:
    phases:
      preBuild:
        commands:
          - aws event put-events ....
      build:
        commands:
          - aws event put-events ....
```

Then you can actually create rule to match those events and sent to SNS or your Telegram webhooks may be